# Replying with a json for a Spring Restful Web Service

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC restful webservice which replies back with list of all products.

Currently I am having all the data to return in a List of a Bean.

```
List<ProdBean> results = jdbcTemplate.query("select * from Prods",
    new RowMapper<ProdBean>() {
    @Override
    public ProdBean mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        ProdBean gb = new ProdBean();
        gb.setProdId(rs.getInt("ProdId"));
        gb.setProdName(rs.getInt("ProdName"));
        // Few more params
        return gb;
    }
});

return results; //I want to convert this to a json object.
```

How can I convert the `List<ProdBean> results` to create a json object and use it as a return parameter?

Smthing like -

```
[{"prodId":1, "prodName":"A"}, {"prodId":2, "prodName":"B"}, ... ]
```

Can this be done using some annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `@ResponseBody` annotation. The returned value will be converted to `JSON` (It use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) by default).

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class JSONController {

    /**
     * This method will return [{"prodId":1, "prodName":"A"}, {"prodId":2, "prodName":"B"}, ... ]
     */
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value="/bar", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<ProdBean> getJson() {
        List<ProdBean> results = ...
        return results;
    }
}
```

If you are using `Spring 4`, you can use the new [@RestController](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html) annotation and removed the `@ResponseBody` annotation on the method.

**UPDATE**

you must have those `.jar` on the classpath.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
     <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
     <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
     <version>2.2.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: I am using Spring 4.0, So I just need to replace @ResponseBody by @RestController. When using that I am getting `Error 406 - The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.`

Comment: Do you have <mvc:annotation-driven /> in your config file?

Comment: What are you using on the client side? Also can you post the ProdBean object?

Comment: I am just testing it through Chrome, hitting localhost:8080/prodWS/service. Gave a sysout to test the size of the List size. It printed back accurately.

Comment: can you show the ProdBean object? Maybe Jackson is not able to transform it for some reason... And do you have the jackson jar on your classpath?

Comment: Is there any jar which needs to be added for this? I have added all the default jars i got with Spring 4.0

Comment: Are you using Maven? If so, it should work without doing anything.

Comment: I'm working on creating a gradle. But right now, I'm just exporting the war file through eclipse and putting it in the webapps folder of tomcat directory. Is there any jackson specific jar we need to add in the project?

Comment: Aha! It seems like i have to add `jackson-mapper-asl-1.7.9.jar` and `jackson-core-asl-1.7.9.jar`. Works perfectly now! Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use @responsebody annotation on the return type definition, if you used mvc annotation-driven in your set up it should work fine. The return type will have to match the Json.